# Magento 2 re-index clearing catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1 table

Tags: magento2, search

Every time I re-index the table catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1 gets emptied. Since the table is empty we're unable to search product names or descriptions on the front end. All search results come up with no results.

If we use advanced search SKU and custom Attributes work.

If I add a manual entry into catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1 then it is searchable. As soon as the site is re-indexed it empties the table.

The server did crash (due to host having issues) and it's been happening every since.

No errors running re-index and no errors in any of the logs.

As far as Magento is concerned it thinks it's all working, but something is stopping the catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1 table from filling up with entries.

Which means search on the front end doesn't work at all. It's strange that SKU still works in advanced search.

Products are all showing correctly in their categories both front end and back end. Adding new products and editing existing products are all updating correctly as well - it's just the search.

Has anybody faced this issue before?

Magento 2.2.1, 600 odd products, MariaDB, standard MySQL search

Everything was working fine pre-crash.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com or here.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: Do you still have to add a manual entry after re-index?  Providing the information requested Dec 12, 18 could be beneficial for you.  Let us analyze your MySQL instance data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily a solution, but upgrading to a newer version (in this case 2.2.7) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. I don't know what's causing it. and to make things more interesting, when I downloaded a copy of magento on a local xampp server. After I run the re-index command, the table was generated.

Uploaded the system back on the hosting and then got deleted again.

Then I thought, that there is something wrong with the hosting. I contacted the hosting company, and they assured me that there is nothing wrong.

The problem is that I still cannot work :(

Comment: That's interesting @robert. Did your host have any server crashes or issues prior to you noticing it wasn't working anymore? Do you get any errors in your logs?

Comment: @Justin, no I don't have any errors in my log, and when I contacted the hosting provider, he said that on their side there is nothing that it is showing a problem... so I have been left with the problem and cannot find what is causing it

Comment: @WilsonHauck No, I did not fix the problem. To solve my problem I have changed the hosting service and now it is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue since last few days. catalog_product_index_price table became empty on server and working fine on local server.

After few days research i have found that it's due to different mysql version and import that database with local users.

You can check your local database export file where you can find line as per below where you can find root as user so change it with current_user and import to your server.

```
/*!50013 DEFINER=`root`@`%` SQL */
```

My issue has been resolved by this way.